# Are <form/> name clash risks real with Liferay?

Tags: forms, liferay

I followed the liferay helloword tutorial:
https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/writing-your-first-liferay-application#creating-a-form

It says forms in a liferay application form should always have contain the portlet basename as the name, not to clash with the form name of another portlet.

```
<aui:form action="<%= addEntryURL %>" name="<portlet:namespace />fm">
</aui:form>
```

Why is this precaution not necessary with buttons from unnamed button rows?

```
<aui:button-row cssClass="guestbook-buttons">
    <portlet:renderURL var="addEntryURL">
        <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/html/guestbook/edit_entry.jsp"></portlet:param>
    </portlet:renderURL>
    <aui:button onClick="<%= addEntryURL.toString() %>" value="Add Entry">
    </aui:button>
</aui:button-row>
```

I mean, any portlet could have a page nammed "/html/guestbook/edit_entry.jsp", right?

Plus, I tried to remove this precaution for the form and duplicate my portlet, and did not have any name clash problem. So how is it useful?

Using Liferay 6.2.

Comment: I think it is not more as a recommendation to keep the name of forms unique. The developer of liferay converts this recommendation into a mandantory issue. Think about it: The browser receives a html site with couple of forms. How can your backend determine wich form contained the inputs? As far as concernd the buttons, you can use the form element as a style element. That is my theory, I've got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### About Namespacing

Your portlet's namespace is automatically prefixed to the name of AUI tags in my 6.2 portal.  These two are equivalent in name

```
<form name="<portlet:namespace />fm"</form>
<aui:form name="fm"></aui:form>
```

As a side not they also both with have an id attribute that is just a copy of the name attribute.  If you look at the Liferay source code you will see that almost all the forms are given the name "fm".  This convention is used for convenient and conflicts do not occur because of the namespace prefix.

### Your example

I think your example is a bit off though.  In the case of the unnamed button row, it will always go to the current portlets edit_entry.jsp because of your path specification unless otherwise specified.  However even if you have the same portlet instantiated twice on the same page that really wouldn't make a different.  I don't see to much of an issue with unnamed button rows.

### Conflicts can occur

What would make a difference is if you had the same portlet instantiated twice on the same page. Let's assume for an instance that you have a "pitch" portlet and a "catch" portlet.  Both of them have a class "Portlet" that extends MVCPortlet.  Both of them have fm forms with no namespace.  When posted the form goes triggers an action url which goes to the portlet and subtracts a point.  In this case there could possibly be a conflict and a point subtracted from the wrong portlet.

### Testing it out

To witness a conflict for yourself you can stage the following example.

1. Create two Liferay Plugin Portlets with different names.
2. In both portlets create a Portlet.java file that extends MVCPortlet (see below).  Make sure the fully qualified class name is simply *Portlet* (IE: don't create any packages)
3. In your view.jsp file create a form and an action url (see below).
4. In your Liferay-portlet.xml file add the code below.

**Portlet.java**

```
public class DashboardRequestPortlet extends MVCPortlet {
    public void testAction(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionRequest actionResponse) {
    System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

**View.jsp**

```
<portlet:actionURL name="testAction" var="testActionURL" />
<form id="fm" name="fm" action="<%= testActionURL.toString() %>" method="post"></form>
```

**liferay-portlet.xml**

```
<requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>
```

Put breakpoints in the testAction method on both portlets.  Drag both portlets onto the same page.  Start submitting...

Comment: If I understand well enough, I will have trouble using just `<form name="fm"</form>` but as I used `<aui:form>` instead of `<form>`, the `<portlet:namespace />` in the name was automatically added, thus I could not reproduce the name-conflict problem. Right?

Comment: Well in the example your provided if you inspect the html I think you will see that you actually have two namespaces prefixed to your form name because aui by default puts one there and you explicitly placed on there as well.  The button row might also have the namespace as the name (although im not exactly sure of that), but I don't see how the button row being unnamed would cause a collision in the majority of cases.

Answer (score 1):

One likely possibility is that you have two instances of the same portlet in the same page. In case you are using ids to address your elements in Javascript, the namespace prefix will avoid name clashes.

Or it could just be that two portlets have the same ids for its form elements. In any case, the name clashes which are avoided with this practice are in Javascript.

Comment: I don't see how you can add two times the same portlet to the page, it's grayed out the second time. I also try to add two portlet which have exactly the same code, and I did not have any form problem.

Comment: In order two add two times the same portlet to a page, the portlet has to be instanceable, which is  actually the default. Anyhow, this can be changed in liferay-portlet.xml

In order to reproduce the problem you should have some Javascript which tries to access the form fields by id. Is this the case with your portlets?

Comment: Here you can see how to make a portlet instanceable: https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-1/anatomy-of-a-portlet